# Why does cat x >> x loop?

Tags: shell, files, io-redirection, cat

The following bash commands go into an infinte loop:

```
$ echo hi > x
$ cat x >> x
```

I can guess that `cat` continues to read from `x` after
it has started writing to stdout. What is confusing, however,
is that my own test implementation of cat exhibits different behavior:

```
// mycat.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
  char buf[4096];
  int num_read;
  while ((num_read = fread(buf, 1, 4096, f))) {
    fwrite(buf, 1, num_read, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If I run:

```
$ make mycat
$ echo hi > x
$ ./mycat x >> x
```

It does *not* loop. Given the behavior of `cat` and the fact that I'm
flushing to `stdout` before `fread` is called again, I would expect this C code to continue reading and writing in a cycle.

How are these two behaviors consistent? What mechanism explains why `cat` loops while the above code does not?

Comment: It does loop for me. Have you tried running it under strace/truss? What system are you on?

Comment: It seems BSD cat has this behaviour and GNU cat reports an error when we try something like this. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3887969/1742825) answer discusses the same and I believe you are using BSD cat since I have GNU cat and when tested got the error.

Comment: I'm using Darwin. I like the idea that `cat x >> x` causes an error; however, this command is suggested in Kernighan and Pike's Unix book as an exercise.

Comment: `cat` most likely uses system calls instead of stdio. With stdio, your program may be caching EOFness. If you start out with a file larger than 4096 bytes, do you get an infinite loop?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, yes! The C code loops when the file is over 4k. Thanks, perhaps that is the entire difference right there.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You should post an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On an older RHEL system I've got, `/bin/cat` does *not* loop for `cat x >> x`. `cat` gives the error message "cat: x: input file is output file".  I can fool `/bin/cat` by doing this: `cat < x >> x`.  When I try your code above, I get the "looping" you describe.  I also wrote a system call based "cat":

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
        char buf[4906];
        int fd, cc;
        fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY);
        while ((cc = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
                if (cc > 0) write(1, buf, cc);
        close(fd);
        return 0;
}
```

This loops, too. The only buffering here (unlike for stdio-based "mycat") is what goes on in the kernel.

I think what's happening is that file descriptor 3 (the result of `open(av[1])`) has an offset into the file of 0. Filed descriptor 1 (stdout) has an offset of 3, because the ">>" causes the invoking shell to do an `lseek()` on the file descriptor before handing it off to the `cat` child process.

Doing a `read()` of any sort, whether into a stdio buffer, or a plain `char buf[]` advances the position of file descriptor 3. Doing a `write()` advances the position of file descriptor 1. Those two offsets are different numbers. Because of the ">>", file descriptor 1 always has an offset greater than or equal to the offset of file descriptor 3. So any "cat-like" program will loop, unless it does some internal buffering. It's possible, maybe even likely, that a stdio implementation of a `FILE *` (which is the type of the symbols `stdout` and `f` in your code) that includes its own buffer. `fread()` may actually do a system call `read()` to fill the internal buffer fo `f`. This may or may not change anything in the insides of `stdout`. Calling `fwrite()` on `stdout` may or may not change anything inside of `f`.  So a stdio-based "cat" might not loop. Or it might. Hard to say without reading through a lot of ugly, ugly libc code.

I did an `strace` on the RHEL `cat` - it just does a succession of `read()` and `write()` system calls. But a `cat` doesn't have to work this way. It would be possible to `mmap()` the input file, then do `write(1, mapped_address, input_file_size)`. The kernel would do all the work. Or you could do a `sendfile()` system call between the input and output file descriptors on Linux systems. Old SunOS 4.x systems were rumored to do the memory mapping trick, but I don't know if any one has ever done a sendfile-based cat. In either case the "looping" wouldn't happen, as both `write()` and `sendfile()` require a length-to-transfer parameter.

Comment: Thanks. On Darwin, it looks like the `fread` call cached a EOF flag as Mark Plotnick suggested. Evidence: [1] Darwin cat uses read, not fread; and [2] Darwin's fread calls __srefill which sets `fp->_flags |= __SEOF;` in some cases.

[1] http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/bin/cat/cat.c
[2] http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/stdio.subproj/refill.c

Comment: This is awesome - I was the first to upvote it yesterday. It *might* be worth mentioning that the *only* POSIX-defined switch for `cat` is `cat -u` - *u* for *unbuffered*.

Comment: Actually, `>>` ought to be implemented by calling open() with the `O_APPEND` flag, which causes _every_ write operation to (atomically) write to the current end of the file _no matter what_ the file descriptor's position was prior to the read. This behavior is necessary for `foo >> logfile & bar >> logfile` to work correctly, for example -- you can't afford to assume that the position after the end of your own last write is still the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

A modern cat implementation (sunos-4.0 1988) uses mmap() to map the whole file and then calls 1x write() for this space. Such an implementation will not loop as long as the virtual memory allows to map the whole file.

For other implementations it depends on whether the file is larger than the I/O buffer.

Comment: Many `cat` implementations don't buffer their output (`-u` implied). Those will always loop.

Comment: Solaris 11 (SunOS-5.11) doesn't appear to be using mmap() for small files (seems to resort to it only for files 32769 bytes large or above).

Comment: Correct -u is usually the default. This does not imply a loop as an implementation can read the whole filesize and do just one write with that buf.

Comment: Solaris cat only loops if the filesize is > max mapsize or if the initial fileoffset is != 0.

Comment: What I observe with Solaris 11. It does a read() loop if the initial offset is != 0 or if the filesise is betwen 0 and 32768. Above that, it mmaps() 8MiB large regions of the file at a time and never seem to revert to read() loops even for PiB files (tested on sparse files).

Answer (score 0):

As written in [Bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file), **you cannot read from a file and write to it in the same pipeline.**

> Depending on what your pipeline does, the file may be clobbered (to 0
>   bytes, or possibly to a number of bytes equal to the size of your
>   operating system's pipeline buffer), or it may grow until it fills the
>   available disk space, or reaches your operating system's file size
>   limitation, or your quota, etc.

The solution is to either use text editor, or temporary variable.

Answer (score -1):

You have some kind of race condition between both `x`. Some implementations of `cat` (e.g. coreutils 8.23) forbid that:

```
$ cat x >> x
cat: x: input file is output file
```

If this is not detected, the behavior will obviously depend on the implementation (buffer size, etc.).

In your code, you could try to add a `clearerr(f);` after the `fflush`, in case the next `fread` would return an error if the end-of-file indicator is set.

**EDIT:** The behavior has eventually been [discussed in the Austin Group](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=876), allowing a failure.

Comment: It seems that a good OS will have deterministic behavior for a single process with a single thread running the same read/write commands. In any case, the behavior is deterministic for me, and I'm mainly asking about the discrepancy.

Comment: @Tyler IMHO, without clear specification on this case, the above command makes no sense, and determinism isn't really important (except an error like here, which is the best behavior). This is a bit like C's `i = i++;` undefined behavior, hence the discrepancy.

Comment: No, there is no race condition here, the behavior is well-defined. It is however implementation-defined, depending on the relative size of the file and the buffer used by `cat`.

Comment: @Gilles Where do you see that the behavior is well-defined/implementation-defined? Can you give some reference? [POSIX cat specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) just says: "It is implementation-defined whether the cat utility buffers output if the -u option is not specified." However, when a buffer is used, the implementation doesn't have to define how it is used; it may be non-deterministic, e.g. with a buffer flushed at random time.

Comment: @vinc17 Please insert “in practice” in my previous comment. Yes, that's theoretically possible and POSIX-compliant, but nobody does it.