# cat redirection

Tags: files, io-redirection, cat

Say a file called `abc` exists in the current directory and it has some text in it. When you execute the command:

```
cat abc > abc
```

Why do the contents of the the file `abc` disappear?
Why does the command delete the text in it and the file becomes an empty file?

Comment: And for solutions, see [Can I make `cut` change a file in place?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/can-i-make-cut-change-a-file-in-place)

Comment: A **laser pointer** is a very effective tool for **cat redirection.**  *</pun>*

Comment: My cat responds very poorly to redirection...

Comment: To avoid this issue, I use a little shellscript which I called [dog](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh/blob/master/code/shellscript/stream/dog.sh): `cat abc | dog abc`

Comment: Another option, if you don't mind the output on screen, is to use `tee`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because of the order how things are done.

When you do:

```
cat abc > abc
```

`>` is the output redirection operator, when the shell sees this it opens the file in truncation mode using `O_TRUNC` flag with `open(2)` i.e. `open("abc", O_TRUNC)`, so whatever was there in the file will be gone. Note that, this redirection is done first by the shell before the `cat` command runs.

So when the command  `cat abc` executes, the file `abc` is already truncated hence `cat` will find the file empty.

Comment: What about cat abc >> abc ? What happens then?

Comment: @TulsiKanodia - that causes an infinite loop. Each time cat reads a line, it appends another before moving to the next.

Comment: This is detected and prevented. Instead, the text `cat: filename: input file is output file` (where `filename` is the filename you chose) is printed on the old stdout.

Comment: @TulsiKanodia See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154903/why-does-cat-x-x-loop

Answer (score 5):

Adding to [@heemayl's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306440/3645), if you want the code to be more clear about the sequence in which things are happening you can simply put the any redirections at the start of the command:

```
> abc cat abc
```