# Delete lines containing the pattern and the line before

Tags: sed

I'd like to delete two lines in a file, containing pattern `aaa bbb ccc`.

I have used the following expression, which deletes the line containing
pattern `aaa bbb ccc` and the line before.

```
$ sed -n '/aaa bbb ccc/{s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' file.txt | sed '/^$/d'
```

This works for one file. It doesn't work for multiple files

```
$ for i in *.txt; do sed -n '/aaa bbb ccc/{s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' "$i" | sed '/^$/d'; done
```

example file:

```
xxx
yyy
aaa bbb ccc
eee
fff
aaa bbb ccc
ggg
hhh
```

result file:

```
xxx
eee
ggg
hhh
```

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Do you want to delete two lines containing the pattern, any line containing the pattern, or the line(s) containing the pattern and the immediately preceding line?

Comment: @Kusalananda I reworded the heading.

Comment: @xralf, can you share the input example and the final expected result?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, I added example to the question.

Comment: @xralf - I've created 3 .txt files, based on your example, and I execute the for loop you shared, and it worked for me. Note: I'm using bash version 4.3.48, sed GNU version 4.2.2

Comment: @Yaron My version is `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Quite easy `ed -s your_file <<< $',$g/aaa bbb ccc/-1,.d\nw'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're using `gnu sed` - in that case you can do something like

```
sed -s 'N;/PATTERN/!P;D' ./*.txt
```

With other `sed`s you'd have to loop over the list of files

```
for file in ./*.txt
do
sed '$!N;/PATTERN/!P;D' "$file"
done
```

This will always keep two lines in the pattern space and print the first one if the pattern space doesn't match so with an input like

```
some line
PATTERN
PATTERN
more
lines
another line
PATTERN
```

it will print

```
more
lines
```

Comment: One detail. The above command writes only to standard output.
When I extend the command as follows `... "$file" > "$file"`, it will delete the content of the file, instead of replacing it with modified content.

Comment: @xralf - it's quite surprising that someone who has been here for over six years doesn't know what `some command "$file" > "$file"` does (that is, truncating the file)... I mean, really, it has been asked _and answered_ a million times...

Comment: In many subjects I haven't started learning from the beginning, but because I needed to have something done. I usually tell to myself, I will learn it from the beginning someday. :-) Thanks anyway, when I have serenity time, I like helping others as well.

Comment: @xralf - no problem, that's how I've learned too lol... I wasn't criticizing you, it was just hard to believe that you had never tried (even accidentally) to [`cat file > file`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306438) or seen similar posts here (they pop up every other week or so...)